# MarkLogic CORS Headers

Tags: marklogic

If we want to connect to a MarkLogic REST endpoint using an AJAX request from a different host or port, am I correct in thinking that MarkLogic does not allow adding headers to the built-in REST endpoints to avoid the CORS issue?

I believe I can get around this by using an xquery script and connecting to this - and adding the following to the xquery script:

```
 xdmp:add-response-header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 xdmp:add-response-header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, x-requested-with, content-type");
```

So e.g. instead of connecting to the "v1/documents?uri=" endpoint, I could just connect to a "documents.xqy?uri=" script that provided the same functionality. Is there a downside to this approach? Is there a better way to handle this?

I notice that another option given in the past has been to use a reverse proxy but I assume this is un-necessary given the approach above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you build custom XQuery endpoints instead of using the REST API, then yes, you can set response headers and you should be fine. The only downside would be losing out on the out-of-the-box functionality of the REST API.

Another approach is to use a middle tier between your client-side JavaScript and MarkLogic and handle the CORS issue there.

What you don't want to do is have your [client-side JavaScript talk directly to the REST API](http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/use-a-middle-tier) -- that's kind of like having an ODBC connection publicly available. (It's fine to do that for a proof-of-concept, but not a good idea for production.)

Comment: I second Dave's assertion.  To quote his fine article (linked in his response) that more fully addresses the topic, "The MarkLogic REST API was built with a three-tier architecture in mind, where that middle tier applies business logic to ensure that only proper requests get through to the REST API."  Expose only business-logic-defined endpoints on public networks, not the granular and powerful REST API endpoints.

Comment: Thanks! This is for use on a private network using LDAP authentication with Marklogic. Are the concerns outlined in Dave's article are less of a concern given this use case?

Also, I know one option to get around the CORS issue is to extend the REST API so that the relevant headers can be added. The approach we are using, as discussed, is to connect to xquery scripts and add the headers there. Is there a disadvantage to doing this over extending the REST API or does it just depend on the use case?

Comment: Use on a private network reduces the number of people who could attempt to act beyond their authorization, but doesn't change the problem itself. If you're committed to a two-tier app (a perfectly reasonable architecture), the advice is to roll your own endpoints to ensure fine-grained control over what people can do.